# Not getting all iOS Gmail notifications when "Important only" is selected

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, gmail, notifications

In the latest version of the iOS Gmail app released on June 4, they added a feature that allows users to choose to only receive notifications for "Important"/"Priority" emails. This option is only available to users that are using the "Important first" inbox or "Priority Inbox" in the web version of Gmail.

I'm using the "Important first" inbox. I chose to only send me iOS notifications for "Important only". However, I'm not getting notifications for all important emails. I know this because the badge for the Gmail app is updated correctly, but I don't get any lock screen notifications for all these emails. I get notifications for about 25% of all Important emails, and the rest I don't get notified.

I already tried deleting the app and reinstalling it, but that didn't work. Anyone know if this is a known bug of the app? I recall another bug where the app would continuously notify the user by sending notifications for the same email over and over again, until they deleted and reinstalled the app.

Answer (score -1):

the new upgraded altamail app has come out today, it might be worth checking this out instead of using the gmail app, i think it might offer more flexibility than the latter as well
been using it with my gmail email and other accounts over the last few months and it seems to offer much more in terms of notifications